# Analog Devices M5L package

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification

I have an IC in a 10-pin MSOP package, labeled `M5L`. I don't understand what it is.  See the lower left area in this picture:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the [ADM1191](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/adm1191.pdf) Digital Power Monitor?

The package is a 10-pin MSOP, and the branding could match:

[image]

You'd have to check if the connections make sense (pin 1 connected to V<sub>CC</sub>, pin 4 connected to GND, ...).

[image]

Comment: Thank you The product with the code ADM1191 is the same as M5L

Comment: @Electronicrepair - Hi, You posted the above comment as an "answer", however it just seems to be confirming that *this* answer is correct, so I moved it to be a comment here. Please see the [tour] & [help] for the main site rules here. Also please see [this page](/help/someone-answers). If your question has been solved, please consider "[áccepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234)" your choice of the best answer i.e. click the "tick mark" next to that answer to make it green. That shows you don't need more help & future readers can quickly see the confirmed solution. Thanks.